# How to paste graphics precisely where the cursor is blinking in MS Word 2013?

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-word-2013

I created graphics using Shapes toolbar and grouped them and copying one object and pasting it in another Word document.

The problem is when I paste graphics it appear in middle of document every time and I have to drag it to where my cursor was.

How I can paste objects directly to where the cursor is?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the way Word pastes in `File > Options > Advanced > Cut, copy, paste`.

Find the setting `Insert/paste pictures as:` and set it to `In line with text`.

[image]

Note: my version is 2010, so it may look different. Same principle applies.

Comment: This does not seem to work at all in Word 2016.

Comment: Well, the OP was asking about 2013 and never responded to my answer. Thanks for the input.